# Unable to determine whether the interceptor is working or not in Struts2

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I have configured `struts.xml` file as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.struts2examples.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/AccessDenied.jsp</result>
            <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="timer" />
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

It should log the time of execution action `hello`. When I am calling the `hello` action on server, Logs get generated in tomcat logs as :

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2013:17:24:38 +0530] "GET /StrutsHelloWorld/Login.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 1033
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2013:17:29:30 +0530] "POST /Struts2HelloWorld/hello HTTP/1.1" 200 129
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2013:17:29:41 +0530] "POST /Struts2HelloWorld/hello HTTP/1.1" 200 105
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2013:17:31:04 +0530] "POST /Struts2HelloWorld/hello HTTP/1.1" 200 105
```

Nowhere the interceptor logs are shown. I am accessing the 
`localhost_access_log.2013-11-18.txt` file in tomcat logs. Am I accessing the wrong file? If it is then where would be the logs generated?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specified which library you are using (eg. Log4j), nor how it's configured, but you should look inside your log file, not in tomcat one.

From [the documentation](http://com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.TimerInterceptor):

> This interceptor logs the amount of time in milliseconds. **In order for
>   this interceptor to work properly, the logging framework must be set
>   to at least the INFO level. This interceptor relies on the [Commons
>   Logging API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) to report its execution-time value**.
>
> ## Parameters
>
> - `logLevel` (optional) - what log level should we use (trace, debug, info, warn, error, fatal)? - **defaut** is **info**
> - `logCategory` (optional) - If provided we would use this category (eg. com.mycompany.app). **Default** is to use
>     **com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.TimerInterceptor**.
>
> The parameters above enables us to **log all action execution times in
>   our own logfile**.

That said, you are using only TWO interceptors; it would be better to add the Timer Interceptor to the defaultStack or at least to the basicStack (or to a custom stack of your). Putting it after the stack will log only Action's execution time, while before the stack will log Interceptors's execution time too:

Log only Action's execution time:

```
<action name="hello" class="com.struts2examples.HelloWorldAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="timer" />
    <result>/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/AccessDenied.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Log Action's and Interceptor's execution time:

```
<action name="hello" class="com.struts2examples.HelloWorldAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="timer" />
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <result>/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/AccessDenied.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Note that `method="execute"` or `result name="success"` are not necessary because they're the default.

Comment: I am following the tutorial at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_interceptors.htm . I set a logging.properties file for the above code as :  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
I didn't do anything else. Can you help me out?

Comment: Your logs are messed up btw, (all those leading 0s and 1s, etc). Just switch from Apache logger to log4j for a successfull living: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j